# asynctask custom progressdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am new android developer and I work on asynctask, I want to need native ads on progress dialog like this:

[image]

I use XML layout but cannot showing if any body knowing please guide me I implement.
How this is possible? Please help me.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String resp;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    View customProgress;

    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        try {
            int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]) * 1000;

            Thread.sleep(time);
            resp = "Slept for " + params[0] + " seconds";
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resp;
    }

    /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    *
    * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
    */
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        finalResult.setText(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    *
    * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
    */
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading! Please wait...!" + time.getText().toString() + " seconds");

        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us AdMob by google to show ads on your app:
**https://www.google.com/admob/**

You can follow this tutorials to use AdMob on your app.

**http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/**

You can refer **SecondActivity** to show full screen ads from this tutorial. You can put it directly in your **AsyncTask** to show ad.